# Android app with onClickListener not working

Tags: java, android

When I run the app in android emulator, it crashes. Does anybody know, what's wrong in this code?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button pl_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);

        pl_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your logcat..

Comment: The program crashes or the emulator crashes?  What error do you get?  What's in your logcat?

Comment: don't use final and check if in your main layout the play_button exists

Comment: First of all, your activity should not be `abstract`. And if you implements `OnClickListener` then you have to implement the method `onClick(View v)`.
Try to remove the `abstract` and the `OnClickListener` interface of your Activity (declaration will be like `public class MyActivity extends Activity {`).
Also, double check your AndroidManifest.xml to see if its in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is implementing `OnClickListener` interface, but does not really implements its `onClick` method. I guess that's why you had to put `abstract` modifier.

Remove `abstract`, remove `implements OnClickListener` from MyActivity declaration and try again.

Next time include logcat output with exception stack trace.